# Do i need ASP.Net core if I have no plans to host my app anywhere other than IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am going to start a ASP.Net project tomorrow.
ASP.Net with Web API, Angular 2 are in my plans, but I am concerned about .Net core as my project life time will be 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my view of your situation if you do not have any future plans to migrate from Windows platform.

I do not have much experience with .Net Core, but I think .NET framework can offer much more than .NET core a this point. It's more tested, it's older which means it is probably more stable and not prone to changes as younger libraries.

Example for, Entity Framework Core is still missing some features which are offered in standard Entity Framework.

I'm not saying that this will not change, just trying to describe current situation.

For more detailed help, I guess you should post more information about your project.

Answer (score 0):

The AspNetCoreModule has to be installed on your server and is part of the ASP.NET Core Server Hosting Bundle.

For detail information of installing and configuration. Please visit the following website.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use ASP.NET Core with full .net framework. You're not obligated to use it in a combination with dotnet core.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it depends on how much weight you give to the different arguments.

Generally speaking I vote for ASP.NET Core especially for a new project. You will never know how long the lifetime of the project will be (maybe the anticipated three years will be extended). I list some arguments that came to my mind - and some of them will gain or loose some weight over time.

Pros for ASP.NET Core

- Faster. The ASP.NET Core Team and the community put much effort to make ASP.NET Core one of the fastest Web Frameworks. It is the first time I have heard that people are proud of some benchmarks.
- New framework and in active development with a faster and more fine tuned release cycle. I expect new features to appear on ASP.NET Core faster then (if at all on classic ASP.NET).
- Although Cross-Plattform is not necessary for you now - it will be easier for you to make the move (e.g. Linux)  in the future.
- Starting on Windows you can run you application on top off the full .net framework and use the magnitude of third party libraries.

Pros for ASP.NET (classic)

- Robust - many years of experience in production
- Feature complete (compared to ASP.NET Core, Entity Framework Core, .core)
- Because of its lifetime you will find more people with indepth knowledge